# LWJGL + Swing closing the window

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, lwjgl

I am using an awt canvas inside a `JFrame` for rendering my LWJGL application. When I run my application in Netbeans, I can close the window fine using my

```
destroyOpenGL();
```

method instead of having to use

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Here is the code for my destroyOpenGL() Method:

```
private void destroyOpenGL() {
    obj.destroy();
    obj2.destroy();
    Display.destroy();
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

`obj.destroy();` and `obj2.destroy();` are used to destroy the two VBOs being rendered.

When I clean and build the application into a .jar file and run it, everything works okay, but when I try to close the application, even though the display shuts down correctly, I get the message that java has stopped working from windows.

When I add `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, I get this in Netbeans:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
```

When I clean and build, then run the jar, it closes fine.

I don't understand why this happens and I'm not sure of a solution.

Comment: Where do you add `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`?

Comment: It is added just after I define the frame variable. 'frame = new JFrame();'  It is called in a 'initUI();' method that occurs before the OpenGL is initialized. @TheGuywithTheElfHat